# How to Integrate Magento Social in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-social

I would like to know more about Magento Social which was recently introduced in Magento 2.2. The module is available in the following location.

```
System -> Extension -> Integration -> Magento Social
```

I would like to know about this module and how to integrate and configure it with the latest Magento 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of October 3, 2017, the Magento 2.2 User Guide says the following:

> Your Magento store can be connected to social networks either by using the Magento Social Facebook connector, or by installing a Marketplace extension.  In addition, you can easily add social plugins such as the “Like” button to CMS blocks that can be incorporated into pages throughout your store.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/social.html

As for the dev side, see the module here:

```
/magento2/vendor/shopialfb
```

Comment: Is this extension not active any more?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Magento social, you need to be proficient with coding, ReactJS, GraphQL, and other technologies. This is not easy. Therefore, I want to mention a way helping you solve this issue. You can use [Magento PWA Studio](https://blog.landofcoder.com/methods-to-integrate-pwa-with-magento-2/?utm_source=Stackexchange&utm_medium=Stackexchange_Hau&utm_campaign=Stackexchange_Hau_Traffic) a terrific solution for developers and merchants who want to create their own PWA-powered storefront since it delivers the finest interoperability between your Magento 2 backend and your new PWA storefront.