# How to Activate Magento Social in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento-social

[How to Integrate Magento Social in Magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/how-to-integrate-magento-social-in-magento-2-2)

I refer to link above.

I followed a guide and failed to Activate Magento Social integration. Tried integrate manually but it failed to Activate too. Copied the Consumer Key code line and pasted it into a form and click Send. Got a message: ¨The customer key you've entered cannot be found, please check code.¨

Comment: Did you also follow the instructions from the user guide? http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/social-connect-to-facebook.html